# Angularjs, how call controller from another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to call a controller within another, to give a name to a particular div.

How to call the controller **cook** inside the **myapp-controll** controller?

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<body ng-controller="myapp-controll">

<ng-view></ng-view>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
     .when('/:acess', {
        templateUrl : 'sources/default.html',
        controller  : 'myapp-controll'
     })
});

myapp.controller('myapp-controll', function($scope, $routeParams) {
      $scope.templateUrl = 'sources/'+$routeParams.acess+'.html';
});

myapp.controller('cook', function($scope, $routeParams) {
      $scope.pagetitle = 'cook';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways, some worse than others:

1. You can use scope inheritance by calling up the parent scope from `myapp-controller` using `$scope.$parent`.  This way is very brittle due to the fact that if another scope is introduced in the middle of that chain at some point, your code will break.  This is very possible through things like `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, etc.  Plus, Angular 2.0 is doing away with $scope, so if you want to make your code future proof, I would stay away from this approach.
2. You can use event delegation, by using `$scope.$emit` to send event information up the scope chain:

myapp-controller:

```
$scope.$emit("eventName", eventData);
```

app-controller:

```
$scope.$on("eventName", callbackFn);
```

3. Use a service / factory to communicate between the two.  Since they are singletons, you can inject the service / factory into both controllers and then communicate between the controllers using that.  This is typically the more widely accepted approach to implementing controller-to-controller communication.

Comment: You can also get the element that the controller is sitting on and calling .$scope(), but #3 is really the widely accepted way to deal with cross controllers communication.